# Извлечение базвого домена из домена с географической доменной зоной python

Tags: python, парсер, сеть, domain

Итак, мне нужно извлечь доменное имя из строки.

Такие случаи не создают больших проблем:

```
https://ya.ru/news     >>>    ya.ru
ru.stackoverflow.com   >>>    stackoverflow.com
```

Но решительно неясно что делать в таком случае:

```
school.edu.ru
evil.corp.br
```

`edu.ru` и `corp.br` тут являются доменными зонами, все наиболее очевидные решения ломаются на этом моменте.

Comment: а что такое в вашем понимании "доменное имя"?

Comment: Пробовали tldextract? https://pypi.org/project/tldextract/

Comment: @СергейКох, спасибо! Это очень помогло!